# How to get Yodlee categories with their usages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yodlee

I am working on Yodlee API now I am stuck. I have got categories using 
"/v1/transactions/categories". However, I don't know how to get their usage percentage. There is no clue for that.

I want results like this:-

- Health Care 14%
- Food 10%
- Car Insurance 6%
- Saving 10%
- Charity 10%
- Rent 27%
- Gas 5%
- Car Payment 7%
- Utilities 7%

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check the categories which Yodlee supports-
 https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/transactions/getTransactionCategories

2)Call https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/transactions/getTransactionCount API to get the total transaction count under that user

3)Then call https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/transactions/getTransactionCount API and pass the relevant category id obtained from step 1

4) Finally do a math-

```
((Count of transactions for a category)/(Total transaction count))*100
```

to get the desired output (percentage).

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik